# ffmpeg record before and after applying filters

Tags: video, ffmpeg, tee

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to do the following things:

- acquire input streaming [OK]
- save to disk the video as is [TODO]
- apply filter, i.e. drawtext [OK]
- save to disk the overlayed video [OK]
- preview the overlayed video [OK]

Here my current command line:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <path-to-stream> -vf "[in]drawtext=textfile='text.txt': reload=1: font=arial: fontcolor=red: fontsize=80: box=1: boxcolor=yellow@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2[out]" -vcodec libx264 -f tee -map 0:v "[f=mp4]test.mp4|[f=nut]pipe:" | ffplay pipe:
```

The only thing I don't understand how to do is the recording of the video *before* `drawtext`. I guess I have to create another `tee`:

```
INPUT ---> TEE ---->RECORD
                |
                |-->FILTERS---> TEE ---->RECORD
                                     |
                                     |-->PLAY
```

So I tried with this cumbersome command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <path-to-stream> -vcodec libx264 -f tee -map 0:v "[f=mp4]before.mp4|[f=nut]pipe:" | ffmpeg -f mp4 -i pipe: -vf "[in]drawtext=textfile='text.txt': reload=1: font=arial: fontcolor=red: fontsize=80: box=1: boxcolor=yellow@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2[out]" -vcodec libx264 -f tee -map 0:v "[f=mp4]after.mp4|[f=nut]pipe:" | ffplay pipe:
```

It doesn't throw errors, records "before.mp4" but neither "after.mp4" nor the preview are working. Surely I forgot something in the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the video twice and apply the filter only to the first output stream.

Use

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i <path-to-stream> -map 0:v -map 0:v -filter:v:0 "drawtext=textfile='text.txt': reload=1: font=arial: fontcolor=red: fontsize=80: box=1: boxcolor=yellow@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:v libx264 -f tee "[f=mp4:select=\'v:0\']withtext.mp4|[f=mp4:select=\'v:1\']notext.mp4|[f=nut:select=\'v:0\']pipe:" | ffplay pipe:`